# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-2.7

this is the error im getting when executing my code could someone plz explain what this means??? please!! i am new to python have been using it only a few weeks for a class project but finding myself lost.

```
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/xyz/Desktop/FinalPayload", line 62, in <module>
    mail("jt.kennings@gmail.com","python test","payload from python test",results)

  File "C:/Documents and Settings/xyz/Desktop/FinalPayload", line 42, in mail
    part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your code. We are not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 3):

It means that `attach` is a list when it should be a string. Perhaps you meant to iterate over it?